# SQL Server 2008 R2 GROUP BY or OVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, group-by

I have this table:

```
ID   COLOR    TYPE   DATE
-------------------------------
1    blue      A     2012.02.05
2    white     V     2010.10.23
3    white     V     2014.03.05
4    black     S     2013.02.14
```

I'd like to select only the ID, but in case of 2nd and 3rd rows I want to select the 3rd row because of its latest DATE value.

I have tried this query but it gives back all the two rows:

```
SELECT 
   ID, MAX(DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY  COLOR, TYPE)
FROM  
   TABLE 
WHERE 
   ...
```

How can I select just one column value while I group the rows by other columns, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;WITH CTE AS
 (
  SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COLOR,[TYPE] ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) rn
  FROM TableName
 )
SELECT ID
      ,COLOR
      ,[TYPE]
      ,[DATE]
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
```

### OR

```
SELECT ID
      ,COLOR
      ,[TYPE]
      ,[DATE]
FROM
 (
  SELECT * , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY COLOR,[TYPE] ORDER BY [DATE] DESC) rn
  FROM TableName
 ) A
WHERE rn = 1
```